# Print Arabic word symbols symbols

Tags: python, python-2.7

When you save the Arabic text in a text file, the result is a strange symbol

```
import mechanicalsoup as ms
Browser = ms.StatefulBrowser()
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

url_status = "https://mobile.twitter.com/Orahbeeni/status/1063386449054175232"
Browser.open(url_status)
Browser.follow_link("/Orahbeeni/status/1063386449054175232")
html = Browser.get_current_page()
html = html.decode('utf8')

file_key = open("twtet.txt", 'w+')
file_key.write(str(html))
file_key.close()
```

file twtet.txt :

[image]

Comment: Try opening the file using [`codecs.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) instead of `open()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point setting `sys.defaultencoding`.  Just write the 'UTF-8' data directly to disk.

```
import mechanicalsoup as ms
Browser = ms.StatefulBrowser()

url_status = "https://mobile.twitter.com/Orahbeeni/status/1063386449054175232"
Browser.open(url_status)
Browser.follow_link("/Orahbeeni/status/1063386449054175232")
html = Browser.get_current_page()

with open("twtet.txt", 'wb+') as file_key:
    file_key.write(html)
```

If you open the file, either with Python code or another application, make sure you open as a UTF-8 file.

Comment: Deleting the same symbols